# Implement a vectorized stop loss when price goes below a threshold using pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, vectorization, algorithmic-trading

Given this example DataFrame:

```
date;close;signal;positions
2017-01-02;27.90;0.0;0.0
2017-01-03;27.76;0.0;0.0
2017-01-04;28.65;1.0;1.0
2017-01-05;28.72;1.0;0.0
2017-01-06;28.00;1.0;0.0
2017-01-09;27.03;1.0;0.0 # <<<--- Note the price is -5% when compared to 28.65 (in 2017-01-04)
2017-01-10;28.26;1.0;0.0
2017-01-11;28.35;0.0;-1.0 # <<-- Sell
2017-01-12;29.12;0.0;0.0
2017-01-13;28.99;0.0;0.0
2017-01-16;28.50;1.0;1.0
2017-01-17;28.45;1.0;0.0
2017-01-18;29.06;1.0;0.0
2017-01-19;28.74;0.0;-1.0
2017-01-20;28.76;0.0;0.0
2017-01-23;29.50;0.0;0.0
2017-01-24;29.12;1.0;1.0
2017-01-25;29.87;1.0;0.0
2017-01-26;27.22;1.0;0.0 # <<<--- Note the price is -5% when compared to 29.12 (in 2017-01-24)
2017-01-27;29.76;1.0;0.0 # <<-- still holding the position...
```

I want to implement a "stop loss" when the prices go bellow, let's say, 5%. In this case, the DataFrame should look like as:

```
date;close;signal;positions
2017-01-02;27.90;0.0;0.0
2017-01-03;27.76;0.0;0.0
2017-01-04;28.65;1.0;1.0 # <<-- Buy
2017-01-05;28.72;1.0;0.0
2017-01-06;28.00;1.0;0.0
2017-01-09;27.03;0.0;-1.0 # <<-- Sell with stop-loss
2017-01-10;28.26;0.0;0.0
2017-01-11;28.35;0.0;0.0
2017-01-12;29.12;0.0;0.0
2017-01-13;28.99;0.0;0.0
2017-01-16;28.50;1.0;1.0 # <<-- Buy
2017-01-17;28.45;1.0;0.0
2017-01-18;29.06;1.0;0.0
2017-01-19;28.74;0.0;-1.0 # <<-- Sell with profit
2017-01-20;28.76;0.0;0.0
2017-01-23;29.50;0.0;0.0
2017-01-24;29.12;1.0;1.0 # <<-- Buy
2017-01-25;29.87;1.0;0.0
2017-01-26;27.22;0.0;-1.0 # <<-- Sell with stop-loss
2017-01-27;29.76;0.0;0.0
```

(Please note the changes in 2017-01-09 and 2017-01-26).

Just to make it clear, the "signal" column represents holding positions when it is 1.0. The "positions" column was computed using `df['signal'].diff()` and it represents a buy when equal to 1.0 and a sell when it is equal to -1.0.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: guess I didn't understand your question then, good luck...

Comment: does the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 6):

IIUC now...

```
data['cor_price'] = data['close'].where((data['signal'] == 1) & (data['positions'] == 1), pd.np.nan)
data['cor_price'] = data['cor_price'].ffill().astype(data['close'].dtype)
data['diff_perc'] = (data['close'] - data['cor_price']) / data['cor_price']
data['positions2'] = np.where(data['diff_perc'] <= -0.05, 1, 0)
data
```

[image]

This might be open for improvement, but I took it step by step. First create a column with the corresponding buying price and forward fill. Then create a column with the price differences and lastly create positions2 which shows the result you need.

Comment: Thank you! It is not yet the complete solution but a point where I can start :)

Comment: Please edit your question so I might be able to help.