# Python: How to use ffill() and store calculations in if conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, algorithmic-trading

My code below is checking to see if a certain signal shows it self in some data.

I am trying to implement the solution from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50302942/11739577

especially these lines:

```
data['cor_price'] = data['close'].where((data['signal'] == 1) & (data['positions'] == 1), pd.np.nan)
data['cor_price'] = data['cor_price'].ffill().astype(data['close'].dtype)
data['diff_perc'] = (data['close'] - data['cor_price']) / data['cor_price']
data['positions2'] = np.where(data['diff_perc'] <= -0.05, 1, 0)
```

This is what the data looks like:

```
Index   DATE    NAME    PRICE       ORDER   MACD    MACD_SIGNAL MACD_HIST
33  2020-02-18  Close   39.450001   buy -0.473582   -0.775      0.301418
34  2020-02-19  Close   40.610001   buy -0.314391   -0.682879   0.368487
35  2020-02-20  Close   41.18       buy -0.140616   -0.574426   0.43381
36  2020-02-21  Close   39.959999   buy -0.100187   -0.479578   0.379391
37  2020-02-24  Close   38.669998   buy -0.170276   -0.417718   0.247441
38  2020-02-25  Close   38.41       buy -0.24399    -0.382972   0.138982
39  2020-02-26  Close   37.950001   buy -0.335657   -0.373509   0.037852
40  2020-02-27  Close   36.16       buy -0.546443   -0.408096   -0.138347
41  2020-02-28  Close   34.490002   buy -0.838581   -0.494193   -0.344388
42  2020-03-02  Close   33.98       buy -1.098591   -0.615073   -0.483518
43  2020-03-03  Close   34.169998   buy -1.274626   -0.746983   -0.527643
44  2020-03-04  Close   35.060001   buy -1.327023   -0.862991   -0.464032
45  2020-03-05  Close   34.110001   buy -1.428735   -0.97614    -0.452595
46  2020-03-06  Close   32.82       buy -1.595048   -1.099922   -0.495127
47  2020-03-09  Close   29.040001   buy -2.008712   -1.28168    -0.727032
48  2020-03-10  Close   29.200001   buy -2.297153   -1.484774   -0.812378
49  2020-03-11  Close   29.74       buy -2.453883   -1.678596   -0.775287
```

To give some context:
When the signal, line 1 and line 2 in the code, is triggered a buy takes place: `buy += 1`.

If `buy == 1` I add the buying price to `cor_price` and use `ffill()` to fill `cor_price` "column" in order to calculate the `diff_perc`. As each day goes by and price, which is `index[column][i]` changes. `diff_perc` is the difference between when we bought and at each given day after buying.

When `diff_perc` is < 0.05 `stop_loss` is triggered: `stop_loss +=1` and this means we sell: `sell += 1` and are no longer buying: `buy -= 1`.

How can I implement the stop loss?
I can't seem to attach index[column][i] to cor_price and use ffill()

```
buy = 0
sell = 0
cor_price=0
diff_perc=0
stop_loss=0
temp = 0
stop_loss = 0


if (df["macd_signal"][i+1] < df["macd"][i+1]) != (df["macd_signal"][i] < df["macd"][i]):
    if ((df["macd_signal"][i+1] < df["macd"][i+1]),(df["macd_signal"][i] < df["macd"][i])) == (True,False):
                        
        buy += 1 #we buy as we have spotted a signal
                        
        if sell == 1: #If we previously have sold but make a buy order, sells should be 0
            sell -= 1
                            
        if stop_loss == 1: #If we previously sold on stop loss, but we buy again, stop loss should be 0
            stop_loss -= 1
                                
        if buy == 1: #If we have bought we check if the price is negative, and hits our stop loss meaning we also sell.

            cor_price += index[column][i]
            cor_price = cor_price.ffill().astype(index[column][i].dtype) 
            diff_perc += (index[column][i] - cor_price) / cor_price 
            stop_loss += np.where(diff_perc <= -0.05, 1, 0) 
            buy -= 1 
            sell += 1 

    else:
        sell += 1 #we sell as we have observed a sell signal
        buy -= 1  #as we now have sold, we have no buy orders - until we buy again. 
 
                       
#append to a list to create a pd.DataFrame later                        
BUY_SIGNAL.append(buy)
SELL_SIGNAL.append(sell)
DF_CORR.append(cor_price) 
DIFF_PER.append(diff_perc)
STOP_LOSS.append(stop_loss)
```

Comment: is the sample data missing `macd` and `macd_signal` columns? a bit confused by the question as is

Comment: It is hard to create a recreatable example which is why I link the other SO answer, which I am basically trying to implement.