# Vectorized backtesting using a Pandas Dataframe with stop loss and take profit

Tags: python, pandas, trading, back-testing

I'm looking to do vectorized backtesting using a Pandas Dataframe and I'm having trouble setting a fixed stop loss and take profit.

For example (see image): On 2021-11-26 at 17:44 there is a buy signal (setup == 1) . The purchase would be made if the price breaks the price_entry(5588.5), with the stop loss at 5585.0 and the take profit at 5595.5

I currently do this backtesting using loop, but I need it to be vectored for better performance.

EDIT: I hope to get that result. That is, when finding the exit (stop loss or take profit) of the trading, record the difference (entry price - exit price) in a column.

```
    datetime                    |high   |low    |open   |close  |setup  |price_entry    |stop loss  |take_profit|is_bought  |price_exit |diff
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0   2021-11-26T17:38:00+00:00   |5586   |5583,5 |5586   |5584,5 |NaT    |   NaT         |NaN        |NaN        |           |           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   2021-11-26T17:40:00+00:00   |5585,5 |5583   |5584,5 |5583,5 |NaT    |   NaT         |NaN        |NaN        |           |           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2   2021-11-26T17:42:00+00:00   |5588,5 |5583,5 |5583,5 |5587   |NaT    |   NaT         |NaN        |NaN        |           |           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3   2021-11-26T17:44:00+00:00   |5588   |5585,5 |5586,5 |5585,5 |1      |5588,50        |5585       |5595,5     |           |           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4   2021-11-26T17:46:00+00:00   |5589   |5585   |5586   |5587,5 |NaT    |   NaT         |NaN        |NaN        |True       |           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5   2021-11-26T17:48:00+00:00   |5587,5 |5583   |5587,5 |5584,5 |NaT    |   NaT         |NaN        |NaN        |True       |5585,00    |-3,50
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6   2021-11-26T17:50:00+00:00   |5587   |5583,5 |5584,5 |5586   |1      |5587,5         |5583       |5596,5     |           |           |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7   2021-11-26T17:52:00+00:00   |5586   |5583   |5586   |5584,5 |NaT    |   NaT         |NaN        |NaN        |           |           |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8   2021-11-26T17:54:00+00:00   |5585   |5581   |5584,5 |5583,5 |NaT    |   NaT         |NaN        |NaN        |           |           |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9   2021-11-26T17:56:00+00:00   |5585   |5579   |5584   |5579,5 |NaT    |   NaT         |NaN        |NaN        |           |           |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10  2021-11-26T17:58:00+00:00   |5584   |5577,5 |5579,5 |5581,5 |NaT    |   NaT         |NaN        |NaN        |           |           |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11  2021-11-26T18:00:00+00:00   |5588   |5579,5 |5581,5 |5588   |NaT    |   NaT         |NaN        |NaN        |           |           |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12  2021-11-26T18:02:00+00:00   |5589   |5585,5 |5587,5 |5585,5 |NaT    |   NaT         |NaN        |NaN        |           |           |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
13  2021-11-26T18:04:00+00:00   |5588   |5584,5 |5585,5 |5586,5 |NaT    |   NaT         |NaN        |NaN        |           |           |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14  2021-11-26T18:06:00+00:00   |5586,5 |5583   |5586   |5583,5 |NaT    |   NaT         |NaN        |NaN        |           |           |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15  2021-11-26T18:08:00+00:00   |5585,5 |5582   |5584   |5582   |NaT    |   NaT         |NaN        |NaN        |           |           |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image: Dataframe example]

Comment: What is your expect output? Please update your post with the output of `print(df.head(16).tostring())`.

Comment: Can someone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50302015/implement-a-vectorized-stop-loss-when-price-goes-below-a-threshold-using-pandas